# Interpretation of past error autocorrelation in MA and ARIMA models

Tags: arima

How the past error autocorrelation in MA models should be interpreted semantically ? Is it used to capture a relationship that could not be captured by the available regressors ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context for this? It is a little sparse. I'm not sure how well people will be able to answer your question at present.

Comment: For AR I understand that Y(t) is something * Y(t-1) which make sense as Y(t) is Y(t-1) with more or less a trend or drift or whatever effect. However what can make Y(t) linked to e(t-1) ?

Answer (score 0):

The error autocorrelation is expression for the fact that "the error persists for some time until it dissipates".